# FTP Client with directory monitoring?

Tags: ftp

Are there any FTP clients that can monitor a directory and upload any files placed in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) had some functionality for that. Can't say how well it works becuase I've never used it, but it's worth a look.

EDIT: I think this is the feature: [Keep remote directory up to date](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date)

Answer (score 2):

WinSCP does not always work and is slow on detecting changes.

If found a faster alternative, not open source, but **freeware**.

http://beanland.net.au/autover/

Uploads the changed file within seconds after it has changed.

Comment: Thanks, I think this should be the answer.

Comment: I agree. It monitors folders and use deep comparison with WinMerge